# How can I process a large http response body from a Druid query in Go

Tags: go, druid

I am currently querying Druid and returning a large dataset back (roughly 4-5GBs). I would like to process this response and decode the JSON into a list of structs. I have it working fine when I change the query to return a smaller dataset but as soon as the response gets too large I get an `unexpected EOF` error.

I have tried reading the entire response body

```
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

Decoding the response body directly

```
var object []NewObject
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&object)
```

Creating a buffer and writing to a file

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/test.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
defer f.Close()
const oneMB = 1024 * 1024
bytesRead := 0
respBuf := make([]byte, oneMB)

// Read the response body
for {
    n, err := resp.Body.Read(respBuf)
    bytesRead += n

    if err == io.EOF {
        break
   }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading HTTP response: ", err.Error())
        break
    }

    if _, err = f.Write(respBuf); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

All of these have ended with me getting an `unexpected EOF` error. I am using the default `net/http`, and `encoding/json` module which appear they should work fine. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Why can't you paginate the response? I can't think of any reason at all that you need to send 4-5GB to a client as a response at once; you shouldn't even really have an entire 4-5GB sitting on the back-end (you can't pull *smaller* datasets from Druid?)

Comment: I am querying for events that have occurred in the past day. If I don't include the entire day there is the chance some events could be missed. I suppose I could change it to something like get me all events for each hour but I was trying to limit the number of requests to Druid.

Comment: You can try decoding individual elements of the JSON array, and sending them one by one.

Comment: You must not use respBuf past n, and ["callers should always process the n > 0 bytes returned before considering the error"](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) returned by Read. I strongly suggest to use [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) instead of trying to re-implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem. It appears to be that Druid has a hard query timeout (this [link](https://support.imply.io/hc/en-us/articles/360034310953-Tuning-Druid-for-Large-Result-Sets) explains more about these configuration settings). What is interesting is it appears if you want the response as an object and it is too large it will just cut off mid byte stream, but if you want the result as array and it is too large it will send the bytes to finish the current element and then send a closing `]` so when you parse the result it appears it all came through (no errors), though you may have been cut off midstream.